# Arduino , python , pyfirmata , standard firmata

Tags: arduino-mega, uart, python, adc, analogreference

Is there a way to change arduino analog reference to EXTERNAL IN PYTHON using pyfirmata or any other library ?
Necessary Links : https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/

My sensor has a 3.3 volt operating voltage , my arduino has a 5 volt operating voltage.
As such in arduino using C++ and arduino module the scaling can be done using analogReference(External) and providing reference voltage to analog read?

IS there any equivalent to this in python, pyfirmata ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as I know. The firmata protocol does not include a command to set the analog reference. However, you can of course modify the firmata firmware to your liking. In the simplest case, just add the appropriate command to the `setup()` function of the main .ino.

Comment: I have been using pyfirmata for the previous projects. Since pyfirmata doesnt include the necessary function , you suggest adding analogreference(External) to the firmata module that i would have to upload and run on arduino , would that make the analog reference voltage external when accessing with pyfirmata and python?

Comment: @Shahanhasan Yes. Firmata doesn't use `analogReference()` anywhere in the code, so when you add `analogReference(EXTERNAL)` to the startup code, it should change the behavior when accessing it from pyfirmata.